# how to split the table based on date into two tables from existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table consisting of records from 2008 to 2014. Now I want to split them as historical and current (recent 3 years including 2014).

I have tried these 2 queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
INTO   DESTINATION_TABLE 
FROM   SOURCE_TABLE 
WHERE  DATE LIKE '%2011%'
```

This query is working, but the `destination_table` was not shown in the related database, another query I have worked on is:

```
CREATE TABLE DESTINATION_TABLE AS 
  (SELECT DISTINCT * 
   FROM   SOURCE_TABLE 
   WHERE  DATE LIKE '%2011%')
```

The above query is showing the error at "as"

So I need the appropriate query.

Comment: Use a Select Distinct * INTO destination_table  from Source_table where date like '%2011%'

Comment: What do you mean by "not shown in the related database"?

Comment: Did you refresh the object explorer after running query 1?

Comment: are you looking for dates of a particular year (2011)?  If so you should use YEAR() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
INTO   Destination_table 
FROM   Source_table
WHERE  YEAR(date) = '2011'
```

Answer (score 1):

For the second statement, use:

```
SELECT TOP 0 * 
INTO   DESTINATION_TABLE 
FROM   [DBName].[dbo].SOURCE_TABLE 
WHERE  DATE LIKE '%2011%'
```

if your SQL Server version supports that.

Also wondering if you're trying to create a table in a remote DB, which is more complex.